# EPSON L395 Installation does not work

Tags: printing, epson

Why can I not install an **Epson L395** printer and make it work on Ubuntu 18.04?  All installations end OK, but then it says it is a generic matrix printer.

Comment: According to Epson, it is the Epson ESC/P-R driver that supports your printer.  http://download.ebz.epson.net/dsc/du/02/DriverDownloadInfo.do?LG2=EN&CN2=&DSCMI=77204&DSCCHK=6002f87ca8f9981189574a3a1ca2ce4ae09fe5a5

Comment: Terrence kindly points you to the Epson site; and if you are using 64bit Ubuntu, you need the epson-inkjet-printer-escpr_1.6.23-1lsb3.2_amd64.deb and if you click to download, and you are offered to open, that should mean gdebi installer will offer to open, which means install. If instead you opt to save it, then double click in your Downloads folder on this package, to prompt installation

Answer (score 1):

Drivers should be downloaded from epson support site.

Remove the printer and add it again , it should work fine!